# how to make product version number?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How to set version number in Eclipse RCP 3.6 application product?

Also, how to make auto upgradeable software like antivirus and others?

Answer (score 1):

Product version can be changed by product definition editor. Edit your *.product file with it.

Usually autoupdate is done via usual [p2 repository mechanism](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-25.htm) - you provide an update site with features to be kept up to date, and user invokes updates check from RCP's help menu (or uses scheduling)

[Read further](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-25.htm) about eclipse packaging

Comment: how to set version number in product definition editor

Comment: Open the product file with the editor, edit version field, save, close editor. Strange question.

Comment: one another question what is difference between product configuration based on plug-in and features

Comment: Ask it as another question on StackOverflow then. You should not ask more then one question in a single post.